# Extract string using regex

Tags: regex

I have a string like

```
1372110902.747405 29245 verbose [paymentserv]: === AUTH: ExternalFundingAnalysisStage was successful (rc:0) ===
```

i want only

```
AUTH: ExternalFundingAnalysisStage was successful (rc:0)
```

using regular expression. please help me to sort out the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any language preferences?

Comment: yes its fine any language.

Comment: [Something like this?](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%3D%7B3%7D%5Cs(.%2B)%5Cs%3D%7B3%7D&input=1372110902.747405%2029245%20verbose%20%5Bpaymentserv%5D%3A%20%3D%3D%3D%20AUTH%3A%20ExternalFundingAnalysisStage%20was%20successful%20(rc%3A0)%20%3D%3D%3D)

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify which language you are using your regex in, any language is presumably a valid response.  So, in Perl, you could use the substitution:

```
s/.*=== (.*) ===.*/$1/;
```

or the match:

```
m/=== (.*) ===/;
```

After the match, `$1` will contain the string you wanted to find.

The `.*` after the second `===` in the substitute is unnecessary for the sample line of input, but is symmetric with the `.*` at the beginning of the regex, and symmetry is pleasing.  It protects the substitute command from trailing debris; the match doesn't need the protection.

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP:

```
$var = "1372110902.747405 29245 verbose [paymentserv]: === AUTH: ExternalFundingAnalysisStage was successful (rc:0) ===";
$var = preg_replace("@.*===([^=]+)===.*@i",$1,$var);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be along the same lines (beginning with AUTH, ending with (rc:#)):

```
//JavaScript
var str = "1372110902.747405 29245 verbose [paymentserv]: === AUTH: ExternalFundingAnalysisStage was successful (rc:0) ===";
str = str.slice(str.indexOf("AUTH"), str.lastIndexOf(")")+1);
```

Or with a regex:

```
str = str.replace(/^.+={3}\s(.+)\s={3}$/,"$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you also use java regex for detail follow this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) and in your case you can also use sub-string .

Like:

```
String str ="1372110902.747405 29245 verbose [paymentserv]: === AUTH: ExternalFundingAnalysisStage was successful (rc:0) ==="; 

String str1=str.subString(58,106);
Stirng str2=str.replace("(","");
```

Then you get your required answer